# How to update an install of ClamAV on one VM that is offline after updating it on another VM that is online

Tags: networking, virtualbox, proxy, ubuntu-16.04, clamav

The host OS Windows 10 and I it is running VirtualBox 6.1.12.

- **Guest OS 1 (VM 1)**: Ubuntu 16.04 **headless server**: Network Setting: Adapter 1 attached to Bridged : Network Setting: Adapter 2 attached to Internal network
- **Guest OS 2 (VM 2)**: Ubuntu 16.04 **headless server**: Network Setting: Adapter 1 attached to Internal Network

Installed ClamAV and Squid on both of the VMs.

Disclaimer: I am [reading this guide](https://rasyid.net/2009/02/10/update-clam-anti-virus-definition-offline/), but there are some things I still not sure how to go about doing it. Here are my questions:

1. How to download the latest version on VM 1.
2. After downloading the file, how do I transfer it from VM 1 to VM 2. Both can communicate with each other.

This is my first time doing this, I do not have any prior knowledge. I will appreciate any advice given on this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is [that guide you link to is from 2009](https://rasyid.net/2009/02/10/update-clam-anti-virus-definition-offline/). The download URL it recommends using is dead and the core of the instructions seem to be about putting the files on a USB flash drive.

That said there are two ways to get updated ClamAV files.

### Method 1: Use `sudo freshclam`.

This is the command you can use on VM 1 to have it update files:

```
sudo freshclam
```

Just run that command and the ClamAV databases should be updated.

That said, sometimes you need to restart the ClamAV daemon each time the DBs are updated so run this command:

```
sudo freshclam && sudo service clamav-daemon restart
```

Either way, your ClamAV database files should be updated in the `/var/lib/clamav/` directory at this point.

So at this point, you can copy the files from the VM 1 `/var/lib/clamav/` directory over to VM 2 to place in the same directory there. Again you have to restart the ClamAV daemon on VM 2 after that is done.

### Method 2: Direct download of the ClamAV database files.

If you cannot use `sudo freshclam` for some reason, you can get the updated databases directly from [the official ClamAV download page](https://www.clamav.net/downloads) at these URLs:

- http://database.clamav.net/main.cvd
- http://database.clamav.net/daily.cvd
- http://database.clamav.net/bytecode.cvd

To download those files from the command line you can run these Curl commands:

- `curl -O http://database.clamav.net/main.cvd`
- `curl -O http://database.clamav.net/daily.cvd`
- `curl -O http://database.clamav.net/bytecode.cvd`

Those files should then be placed in the `/var/lib/clamav/` directory of VM 1 and transferred over to VM 2 to place in the same directory there. Then just restart the ClamAV service like this:

```
sudo service clamav-daemon restart
```

Now how to automate that or script a clean way to do that? That is out of the scope of your question. But these basics should get you started.

Comment: Thanks this is very clear and it helps!